# Download HERE JS API for IDE code completion?

Tags: ide, here-api

is there a way to download the here maps JS api 3.x to provide code completion in my IDE (like PHPStorm)?

I didn't find anything in the documentation.

Regards, Kristian

Answer (score 0):

My knowledge of PHPStorm is limited, but are you able to use the javascript files by downloading them using the direct urls  ?

Although you will run into issues when there are updates in the javascript file.

Comment: Yes, this is possible in PHPStorm. But I think, that didn't help anything. As I see, all here js file contents are packed in an eval function.